# Mysql Join multiple Query

Tags: mysql

I have three tables. I am trying to write a query for that

I have written two Queries for that

**1)**

```
SELECT  
   `user_favourite_bookmarks`.`user_bookmark_id` as `is_fav`,
   `user_bookmarks`.* FROM `user_favourite_bookmarks` 
     RIGHT JOIN 
    `user_bookmarks` ON `user_favourite_bookmarks`.`user_bookmark_id` =    `user_bookmarks`.`bookmark_id` 
   WHERE 
 `user_bookmarks`.`user_id`=26 
 group by `user_bookmarks`.`bookmark_id`
 order by created_at DESC
```

and second query below

**2)**

```
 SELECT  `user_deleted_bookmarks`.`bookmark_id` as `is_deleted`,`user_bookmarks`.*, FROM `user_deleted_bookmarks`
RIGHT JOIN 
**`user_bookmarks` ON `user_deleted_bookmarks`.`bookmark_id` = `user_bookmarks`.`bookmark_id` 
WHERE 
`user_bookmarks`.`user_id`=26 
group by `user_bookmarks`.`bookmark_id` 
order by created_at DESC
```

These Queries are running Accurate

now my first query gives me out like 
**is_fav, title**
and 
second one

**is_deleted, title**

But i want result something like that 
**is_fav, is_deleted, title**

Anybody tell me how to achieve this result. I want to achieve this result in mysql .

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Merge those two queries into one query.

```
SELECT
  b.title,
  IF(f.bookmark_id IS NULL, 'no', 'yes') AS 'favorite',
  IF(d.bookmark_id IS NULL, 'no', 'yes') AS 'deleted'

FROM user_bookmarks b

LEFT JOIN user_deleted_bookmarks d
ON d.bookmark_id = b.bookmark_id

LEFT JOIN user_favourite_bookmark f
ON f.bookmark_id = b.bookmark_id

WHERE b.user_id = 26

GROUP BY b.bookmark_id
ORDER BY b.created_at DESC
```

Comment: there is not such field like is_fav, Please read my query carefully

Comment: @Hitu Sorry Sir, I updated the answer in respect to your avail columns!

Comment: Can you tell me how to get records if deleted is no only from above statement